# Delegating to the default move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I often find myself writing tedious move constructors for classes with many member variables. They look something like the following:

```
A(A && rhs) :
    a(std::move(rhs.a)),
    b(std::move(rhs.b)),
    c(std::move(rhs.c)),
    d(std::move(rhs.d)) {
    some_extra_work();
}
```

That is, they perform all of the actions associated with the default move constructor, then peform some mundane extra task. Ideally I would delegate to the default move constructor then perform the extra work, however the act of defining my own move constructor prevents the default implementation from being defined, meaning there's nothing to delegate to.

Is there a nice way to get around this anti-pattern?

Comment: Difficult to say on such abstract level, but perhaps you could separate `A` into two classes and put one into another? One will have all default constructors and other one will do `some_extra_work`. Check *Rule of zero*.

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable, but would something like `A(A&& rhs, int) : A(rhs){}` not work?

Comment: An intermediate base class with a default move constructor may help.

Comment: @Damon that wouldn't work as it wouldn't be selected by the compiler as a valid move constructor. @zch I think you're probably right, this anti-pattern may be more of an indication that I don't have enough SBRM in A's members (the classic example of some_extra_work() for me is `rhs.d = 0;`).

Comment: IMHO doing extra work essentially means that you are declaring a copy constructor. I'd do what @zch says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: ignore the first part of this answer and skip to the end which has a better solution.

<strike>Wrap the extra work in a new type and inherit from it:</strike>

```
class A;

struct EW
{
    EW(EW&&);
};

class A : private EW
{
    friend class EW;
public:
    A(A&&) = default;
};

EW::EW(EW&&) { A* self = static_cast<A*>(this); self->some_extra_work(); }
```

You could also do it with a data member instead of a base class, but you'd need some hackery using `offsetof` (which is undefined for non-standard-layout types)  or a hand-rolled equivalent using sneaky pointer arithmetic.  Using inheritance allows you to use `static_cast` for the conversion.

**This won't work if `some_extra_work()` has to be done *after* the members are initialized** because base classes are initialized first.

Alternatively if the extra work is actually operating on the rvalue object that you're moving from, then you should wrap the members in types that do that work automatically when moved from, e.g. my [tidy_ptr](https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/tidy_ptr.h#L1) type, which I use to implement the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)

```
class A
{
    tidy_ptr<D> d;
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;
    A(A&& r) = default;  // Postcondition: r.d == nullptr
};
```

Comment: I wonder, isn't the base-class move ctor invoked *before* the member move ctors?

Comment: It is yes, so won't work if the extra work relies on the other members. When I wrote that I hadn't read the OP's comment saying "the classic example of some_extra_work() for me is `rhs.d = 0;`"

Comment: I actually prefer the second part of the answer. Looking back now I think all the cases I've run into this have been where I haven't used SBRM at a low enough level, for example I should be wrapping file descriptors in SBRM classes that call `close`. The rule of zero is really what C++11 should be about.

Comment: Yeah I prefer it too, I should have thought of that sooner, as it's something I actually use and have written a generic tool to support!

Comment: @HostileFork it's now at https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/tidy_ptr.h (I'll update the answer)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I'm reading this by coincidence in 2022. What's the use for tidy_ptr? It looks like a duplicatable unique_ptr.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux are you sure about that? `tidy_ptr` doesn't own its pointer and doesn't free any resources.

Comment: Ah, right. I see. That makes so much more sense. Thanks for the quick clarification :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely, is `tidy_ptr` similar to a unique_ptr with no-op deleter?

Comment: @LouisGo No because it's copyable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "MoveMark" member that becomes `true` when moved,
then do the "extra work" in the destructor:

```
class MyClass {
    MoveMark moved;
    ~MyClass() {
        if (moved)
            std::cout << "Doing extra work on the moved instance...";
    }
}

class MoveMark {
    bool moved = false;
  public:
    MoveMark() {};
    MoveMark(MoveMark && moving) { moving.moved = true; }
    operator bool() const { return moved; }
};
```

Comment: This may be the solution for something, but certainly not for the problem in the original post.